# How to show an example of text classification using SVM with and without SMO in it?

Tags: python, svm, text-classification

I'm trying to make a comparison of text classification between using Support Vector Machine (SVM) with and without Sequential Minimal Optimization (SMO) but I don't know what's the best way to do it.

At first I thought that, for SVM that uses SMO, I can use sklearn's SVM which is based on LIBSVM which uses SMO in it. as for for SVM without SMO, I can't find any type of SVM in Python library that didn't implement SMO in it so I thought of making SVM from scratch but I can't find any examples of it used in text classification.